# Where to put ads in Android, iOS, or other web apps

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

I was not able to find an answer for this but if you sell ad space on an Android app or iPhone app or even a web app, can you choose which activities or windows will display the ad or will all windows and activities display the advertisement?

I am most interested in mobile apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have total control over whether an ad appears or not.

As for how big the ad is, you get to choose from [a set of sizes](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html).

Comment: ok, so in an android app I could have an add appear in some activities but not others?

Comment: Yes. And in those that do have it, you can show/hide it when you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good lesson for android about [Advertising without Compromising User Experience](http://developer.android.com/training/monetization/ads-and-ux.html)